# Ntfs partition is broken and needs repairs. Why does the troubleshot in Winre/Winpe menu is disabled as consequence of that?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, cmd.exe, chkdsk, winpe

Well looks Windows live always look at all disk because even from the install dvd I am landing on this screen [image]
Not only text does not appear but this menu

[image]
([source](https://lecrabeinfo.net/app/uploads/2016/09/acceder-aux-options-de-demarrage-avancees-de-windows-10-options-avancees-57e29d1beaba3-1024x569.png))

is **disabled for an unknown reason**. Which prevent me starting chkdsk.
When I try to boot the real Windows 10, it freezes at the login screen so I can t do anything from there (F8 being disabled I cannot start in failsafe).

On linux, the drive is so corrupt that ntfs-3g fails to mount it read only (but the kernel driver works).

Because this is a hardware raid array which is enabled only when legacy boot is disabled (leaving only UEFI), I can t just take the drive into an other computer.

**How to start cmd.exe in this situation given I can t even reinstall because of that screenshot?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple!

Manually edit the BCD store on the FAT32 uefi partition in order to enable failsafe mode (only command line works and Windows takes more than 100 minutes in a half frozen state to log in).